# Python regular expression string groupings

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match either `@` or the string `at`, like for `name@email` and `nameatemail`. I imagine it's something like

```
regex = '@|at'
```

or

```
regex = '@|(at)'
```

but I just can't find the right syntax.

Comment: Ummm... you're a bit screwed if someone's called Nathan or Natalie aren't you? :)

Comment: Ugh, yes. Good point - thanks!

Comment: @Jon Clements made a good point . for that case, I suggest just keep it for further identification(may be you have a name dictionary in hand) or maintain a list of popular mail service provider , such gmail.com , yahoo.com , then , if you found a string ends with "Nathanatgmail.com", then just translate"atgmail.com" into "@gmail.com" and keep the ”Nathan“ unchanged .

Comment: So in essence you're trying to deobfuscate email addresses? Why? Any plans for spamming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue both `regex` works correctly:

```
match = re.search("@|at", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group()
```

Comment: I didn't realize that it would look at the entire "at", not just the 'a'. You're right! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/) to test your regular expressions (it also provides you with Python code for your regex). And [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for regular expression info.